# Execution of code in other describe blocks - jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, jestjs

I have the following test setup:

```js
describe(`my tests`, () => {
    describe(`Should not run`, () => {
        console.log(`Should not be printed`);
        describe(`Should also not run`, () => {
            console.log(`Should also not be printed`);
            test(`Then an exception is thrown`, () => {
                console.log(`Should definitely not be printed`);
                throw new Error(`whoops`);
            })
        })

        describe(`Should run`, () => {
            console.log(`Should run`)
            test(`Then I should get this list in the format I expect`, () => {
                console.log(`Should definitely be printed`);
            })
        })

        describe(`Should not run`, () => {
            console.log(`Should not be printed`);
            test(`Then I should get an empty list`, () => {
                throw new Error(`whoops`);
            })
        })
    })
})
```

When I ask IntelliJ to *only* run the test case `test('Then I should get this list in the format I expect')`, I still get the following output:

```sh
> Should not be printed
> Should also not be printed
> Should run
> Should not be printed
> Should definitely be printed
```

Howcome the code of the other `describe` blocks is being executed? I thought the `describe` block allowed you to scope test setup so that it only runs for the tests inside that specific block.

Comment: use `describe.only`

Comment: can't reproduce in 2021.3.2 - only the selected test is run (when using the icons in the gutter to start the tests). Tested with jest@25 and jest@27. What IDE and Jest versions do you use?

Comment: Using jest `24.9.0` and IDE IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3 (Ultimate)

Comment: When running the same test in a project that uses jest 27 I still get the same behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this is the [standard and documented behaviour](https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown#order-of-execution-of-describe-and-test-blocks):

> Jest executes all describe handlers in a test file before it executes any of the actual tests. This is another reason to do setup and teardown inside before* and after* handlers rather than inside the describe blocks. Once the describe blocks are complete, by default Jest runs all the tests serially in the order they were encountered in the collection phase, waiting for each to finish and be tidied up before moving on.